# Non-ASCII Characters Not Displayed When Reading From GridFS

Tags: java, http, mongodb, character-encoding, gridfs

I am uploading files (of different content types) using Apache fileupload API as follows:

```
FileItemFactory factory = getFileItemFactory(request.getContentLength());
ServletFileUpload uploader = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
uploader.setSizeMax(maxSize);
uploader.setProgressListener(listener);

List<FileItem> uploadedItems = uploader.parseRequest(request);
```

... saving files to GridFS using the following method:

```
public String saveFile(InputStream is, String contentType) throws UnknownHostException, MongoException {
    GridFSInputFile in = getFileService().createFile(is);
    in.setContentType(contentType);
    in.save();
    ObjectId key = (ObjectId) in.getId();
    return key.toStringMongod();
}
```

... calling saveFile() as follows:

```
saveFile(fileItem.getInputStream(), fileItem.getContentType())
```

and reading from GridFS using the following method:

```
public void writeFileTo(String key, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    GridFSDBFile out = getFileService().findOne(new ObjectId(key));
    if (out == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(key);
    }
    resp.setContentType(out.getContentType());
    out.writeTo(resp.getOutputStream());
}
```

My servlet code to download the file:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String uri = req.getRequestURI();

    String[] uriParts = uri.split("/");  // expecting "/content/[key]"

    // third part should be the key
    if (uriParts.length == 3) {
        try {
            resp.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + (CACHE_AGE * 1000L));
            resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + CACHE_AGE);
            resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

            fileStorageService.writeFileTo(uriParts[2], resp);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    else {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

However; **all non-ASCII characters are displayed as '?'** on a web page with encoding set to UTF-8 using:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you save the file? It is impossible from your code to recognize if the content is corrupted when saving or reading the file. One issue is that resp.setCharacterEncoding has no effect on the OutputStream returned by resp.getOutputStream() and I don't see how the Content-Type meta header on any (which?) HTML page should have any effect on the data you store in GridFS.

Comment: @jarnbjo, I have added the code that reads from HttpServletRequest above.  The code uses Apache Commons FileUpload API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for taking your time!  This was my mistake.  There is nothing wrong with the code or GridFS.  My test file's encoding was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Reason: only content type, together with a binary InputStream are passed on.

```
public void writeFileTo(String key, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    GridFSDBFile out = getFileService().findOne(new ObjectId(key));
    if (out == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(key);
    }
    resp.setContentType(out.getContentType()); // This might be a conflict
    out.writeTo(resp.getOutputStream());
```

}